# How can I disallow certain ciphers for OpenSSH in Fedora, using crypto policies?

Tags: fedora, sshd, cryptography

I would like to disallow certain ciphers for OpenSSH in Fedora.
I've read that Fedora overrides settings in `sshd_config` with its crypto policies.
I'd like to edit those.

My first idea would be to edit `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config`, but I wonder if that is the recommended way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can control settings like encryption ciphers and quite a few other parameters (key exchange algorithms, host-key algorithms, MAC algorithms) under `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` respectively using parameters **`Ciphers`**, `KexAlgorithms`, `HostKeyAlgorithms` and `MACs`. See https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config for more information.

Software like ssh-audit (https://github.com/arthepsy/ssh-audit.git) can help you work out what could do with changing.

Disallowing a cipher happens if you don't list it as an option.

Comment: I've read that Fedora overrides this with its crypto policies. I'd like to edit those.

Comment: Thanks for ssh-audit, it seems useful

Comment: Adjustment to e.g. `KexAlgorithms` via `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` don't work on my Fedora 33 host.

Answer (score 0):

Editing `KexAlgorithms` in `/etc/ssh/sshd.config` won't show any effect, at least not on my Fedora 33 system.

But as you pointed out yourself, you can edit `/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensshserver.config` and `systemctl restart sshd` afterwards. That works perfectly fine.